# One set of apostraphe's are being converted to 3 when I convert my key:value pairs from excel file to YAML

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, openpyxl, pyyaml

I'm trying to write a script that assists with automating raw data from an excel spreadsheet and converts the information found into a YAML file to be used with Ansible.

In my script, I've made several attempts to surround the value in the key:value pair with a set of single quotes. In doing so, the output is always the same which is taking the value, and instead surrounding with 3 quotes instead of one. Of course the ansible file won't be able to be interpreted like this.

An example of what it needs to be

`key: 'value'`

instead I'm getting

`key: '''value'''`or when I try to fix it, `key: value`

Here is a snippet of my code

```
vars = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    vars.update({k: "'{}'".format(v)})


data = {
    'all': {
        'children': {
            'fortigates': {
                'hosts': {
                    'provisioning_ip': {},
                },
                'vars': vars
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've attempted to remove the apostrophes which will get me no apostrophes in my output.
I've attempted to escape the apostrophes, which still shows '''value''' instead of 'value'
I've attempted to update the script to perform slicing like this

`value = value.replace("'''", "'")`

But this removes all apostrophes. Which then shows the output as key: value

I'm at a loss here. I don't know how to get my YAML file to output as just 'value' instead of '''value''' or value.

I've also attempted to use f-strings as a different syntax, but i'm getting the same results.

From feedback from mdaniel, I ommitted the serialization bit of my code. Here is how the data is being serialized.

```
yaml.dump(data, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False,
              Dumper=yaml.Dumper, sort_keys=False)
```

I've also added several print statements to try and debug what's going on. The value's being sent to the YAML are

```
Value in YAML file: {'isp1_name': 'value1', 'upload_download': 'value2', 'isp1_usable_address': 'value3', 'isp1_gateway': 'value4', 'Lab1_subnet_mask': 'value8', 'Lan1_gateway': 'value9', 'Lan1_start_ip': 'value10', 'lan1_stop_ip': 'value11', 'lab2_vlan': 'value12', 'lan2_purpose': 'value13', 'lan2_subnet_address': 'value14'}
```

However, when looking at the actual YAML in the file itself, doesn't include those quotation marks. If I add "" to encapsulate the v variables, it'll then show as ' "value" '

This is so confusing to me. Why does the outside apostrophes appear when I want to quote the value

Comment: Hi EHMars welcome to SO. You omitted the part where you're serializing out the value, but unquestionably if you are using a sane yaml serializer you should not be trying to manually quote anything. If having the single quotes is so incredibly important to you, there's [an option](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#scalars) to put them everywhere, but if you wanted that then just use JSON. Don't add code in comments, instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75127633/edit) to include more details. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel I appreciate the welcomes. I've edited my first post to include the serialization bit of my code. I'm not 100% sure on YAML syntax needs, as the engineer that does the YAML portion, while I'm doing the Python portion told me it needs to be single, or double quotes. And all my attempts at encapsulating the values is just outputting either no single quotes, or 3 sets of them.

Comment: @EHMars Thanks are not necessary on SO and should not be part of question. Upvoting comments or answers that help you is the way  to express gratitude. When you edit a question keep it a single coherent whole, even when updating it based on a comment, don't tag an edit to the end. There is edit history that, if necessary, shows how a question evolved. I would also leave out ansible and openpyxl as tags, they have little to do with the actual problem (just like [tag:ascii] isn't a good tag, although you seem to be using that).

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes (i.e. apostrophes) can have special meaning in YAML, and need escaping if a scalar (in this case your values) start with a single quote.
This escaping is done by doubling the single-quote.

So if you want to dump something that starts with a single quote, you'll get triple quotes at the beginning: the first quote is indicating that a single quoted scalar follows, and the 2nd & 3rd indicate a single quote in the original Python string being dumped.

If you just want all values single quoted, I recommend you upgrade to `ruamel.yaml` (it supports YAML 1.2 **and** YAML 1.1 dumping)

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


def single_quote_values(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, str):
                d[k] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString(v)
            else:
                single_quote_values(v)
    elif isinstane(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            single_quoted_values(elem)
    return d



data = {'isp1_name': 'value1', 'upload_download': 'value2', 'isp1_usable_address': 'value3', 'isp1_gateway': 'value4', 'Lab1_subnet_mask': 'value8', 'Lan1_gateway': 'value9', 'Lan1_start_ip': 'value10', 'lan1_stop_ip': 'value11', 'lab2_vlan': 'value12', 'lan2_purpose': 'value13', 'lan2_subnet_address': 'value14'}

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

yaml.dump(single_quote_values(data), sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```yaml
isp1_name: 'value1'
upload_download: 'value2'
isp1_usable_address: 'value3'
isp1_gateway: 'value4'
Lab1_subnet_mask: 'value8'
Lan1_gateway: 'value9'
Lan1_start_ip: 'value10'
lan1_stop_ip: 'value11'
lab2_vlan: 'value12'
lan2_purpose: 'value13'
lan2_subnet_address: 'value14'
```

Please note that the above changes your datastructure, but the values should still behave like strings. If that is
a problem you can either change the single_quote_value function to create and return different datastructure,
or make a `deepcopy` first.